# Como usar una instanciar la variable conexión de una clase dentro de otra

Tags: php, mysqli, poo

Un saludo para tod@s, he creado una clase para la conexión a la base de datos y creado otra clase para realizar una consulta del total de registros en una tabla. Mi pregunta es: ¿como hago para instanciar o poder usar la variable conexión dentro de la nueva clase para realizar la consulta?.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
require_once 'config/db.php';
class conectarDB
{
    public $con;
    public function conectar()
    {
        # conectare la base de datos
        $conexion  = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        $this->con = $conexion;
        if (!$conexion) {
            die("imposible conectarse: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
        }
        if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Conexión falló: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . " : " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        return $conexion;
    }

}

//Acá se instacia o declara la clase para la conexión
$driver = new conectarDB();

$con = $driver->conectar();

/**
 * Esta clase se usa para contar el total de registros de una tabla
 */
class contadorElementos
{
    public function totalElementos($identificador, $tabla)
    {
        $link      = new conectarDB();
        $con       = $link->conectar();
        $resultado = $con->query("SELECT '" . $identificador . "' FROM '" . $tabla . "'");

/* determinar el número de filas del resultado */
        //$counter = $resultado->num_rows;
        return $resultado->num_rows;
    }
}

$totalizador = new contadorElementos();

$totalRegistros = $totalizador->totalElementos("id_vehiculo", "vehiculos");

echo $totalRegistros;
```

Comment: ¿El problema en sí cuál es? No lo mencionas en tu pregunta. Si preguntas para que hagamos críticas **constructivas** a tu código, tengo varias: `contadorElementos` más que una clase es realmente un método. Una clase es algo más amplio, es una entidad completa con una serie de atributos y métodos. En este caso la clase sería `Elemento` o `Vehiculo`, y uno de sus métodos sería `contar`. Otra crítica: el código SQL es vulnerable a ataque de hackers que puede llegar a un nivel muy serio. Otra: evita el uso de `@`.  Otra: el flujo no está controlado. Otra: respeta la convención de nombres.

Answer (score 0):

en tu segunda clase agrega require_once 'conectarDB.php';
de esa manera podrás usar las variables y métodos de tu clase conectarDB :)